# New kernel does not work properly

Tags: drivers, kernel, hp

I installed kernel version 3.8.8 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/. but after the installation when I booted using the new kernel nothing seemed to work. I have low resolution, network connections are not working. I cant think of a reason for the problem. the older kernel works fine(3.2.x).

I have a hp g630 laptop.

I installed,
    linux-headers-3.8.8-030808_3.8.8-030808.201304170248_all.deb
        linux-headers-3.8.8-030808-generic_3.8.8-030808.201304170248_amd64.deb
        linux-image-3.8.8-030808-generic_3.8.8-030808.201304170248_amd64.deb

If someone knows the reason for this problem please help me to fix this

Comment: Can you confirm that by following the steps discussed in this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade you got the problem you describe?

Comment: @DrSAR - I hadn't installed the last package mentioned there. Now I installed it and kernel is working perfectly. Thanks for posting that up.

Comment: good - feel free to vote on my answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction for installing a kernel without upgrading the distribution [are nicely described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade).

Since these instructions have been tested by many they should have a high chance of succeeding for you.